# How do i fix this countdown timer for it to be aligned?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[This is what i want to achieve using js, html & css but what i got for now is the bottom image][1]
[1]: https://codepen.io/eclairrr/pen/oNJOVao

Comment: You only posted one image.  We can't tell what you're after.